# Python Slot Machine: Calculating Line Payouts

Tags: python

I'm a Python newbie attempting to create a slot machine simulator that mimics the payouts of the real machines. I'm running into an issue in calculating the line payouts, and I'm sure there's a smarter way of iterating through the lines and calculating them.

Defining some constants that I'll be using:

```
SymbolMap = ["Boats","Bonus","Buoys","Clams","Light Houses","Lobsters","Scatter","Seagulls","Starfish","Tuna","Wilds"]

#The ints in reels below are a simpler way to express the SymbolMap above

Reels = [[9,8,3,4,6,3,8,1,5,6,2,3,8,2,3,8,5,4,3,10,7,8,10,1,3,0,8,9,3,8,9,5,3,8,0,4,3,8,0,9,2,7,5,3,8,0,7],
        [3,2,4,3,2,4,1,7,3,0,7,9,0,1,8,7,10,1,7,4,5,10,2,3,1,7,3,6,5,9,7,6,8,3,0,5,7,3,1,8,7,2,4,3,9,7,0],
        [0,8,3,1,4,0,5,8,1,4,8,1,9,8,3,7,8,10,1,4,7,8,9,3,0,9,8,1,9,4,8,6,4,5,7,8,6,2,9,5,1,8,4,7,2,0,9],
        [7,9,2,7,6,2,8,7,9,10,2,9,8,5,7,9,10,5,4,2,7,0,3,8,4,7,0,3,2,7,0,4,8,9,7,2,8,3,2,7,8,3,5,10,2,7,8],
        [3,10,0,5,2,8,4,9,8,4,7,10,9,2,0,3,9,2,8,3,6,2,8,9,3,2,0,4,9,5,4,7,3,5,8,0,4,9,7,8,4,3,5,7,8,3,7]]


# Lines are the row to look for on each reel. i.e. Lines[0] is a straight line of the 2nd row. 
# Lines[3] starts in top left corner of matrix, and forms inverted V shape.

Lines = [[1,1,1,1,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0],
        [2,2,2,2,2],
        [0,1,2,1,0],
        [2,1,0,1,2],
        [2,2,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,2,2],
        [1,2,1,0,1],
        [1,0,1,2,1],
        [2,1,1,1,0],
        [0,1,1,1,2],
        [1,2,2,1,0],
        [1,0,0,1,2],
        [1,1,2,1,0],
        [1,1,0,1,2]]

#Payouts are how many credits won for symbols in a row. For example, Symbols[0] is Boats. 
#2 boats is 0 credits, 3 boats is 25 credits, 4 boats is 100 credits, 5 boats is 500 credits.
#They must be continuous and from left to right. I.e. BOAT-BOAT-CLAM-BOAT-BOAT on a payline wins 0. 
#Similarly, CLAM-CLAM-BOAT-BOAT-BOAT wins 0.

Payouts = [[0,25,100,500],
          [0,0,0,0],
          [0,25,100,500],
          [0,5,30,200]]

#Initializing a 3X5 matrix to represent reels

SpinValues = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]

#Initializing message
Message = ''

#Initializing TotalWin
TotalWin = 0
```

Spin logic, which properly generates a 3X5 matrix of random numbers. **Is there a better way to handle the "if first 3 symbols match" portion, since I'll have to repeat again for 4 symbols and 5 symbols?** Since each line is only entitled to one payout, I'll start with the 5 symbol payouts, then work down toward 2. I started with 3 because it's the most common and will be easiest to test. I'll also have to account for a wild equaling any symbol, which I haven't tried to tackle yet. Likewise, there is a scatter pay (meaning if you have X number of Scatter symbols anywhere in the matrix, you get a payout. That part will be easy). There is also a bonus game, which I'll be working on later:

```
def spin(linesPlayed, wager):
    for i, object in enumerate(Reels):
        length = len(Reels[i])
        StopValue = random.randint(0,length-1)
        SpinValues[1][i] = Reels[i][StopValue]
        if StopValue == 0:
            SpinValues[0][i] = Reels[i][-1]
        else:
            SpinValues[0][i] = Reels[i][StopValue - 1]
        if StopValue == len(Reels[i])-1:
            SpinValues[2][i] = Reels[i][0]
        else:
            SpinValues[2][i] = Reels[i][StopValue +1]
    print(SpinValues[0])
    print("\n")
    print(SpinValues[1])
    print("\n")
    print(SpinValues[2])

    for i in range(linesPlayed):
        #if first 3 symbols match
        if SpinValues[Lines[i][0]] == SpinValues[Lines[i][1]] == SpinValues[Lines[i][2]]:
            PayTable(i,wager,3,SpinValues[Lines[i][0]])
        #if first 4 symbols match
        #if first 5 symbols match
        #handle scatter pay
        #wilds?
        #handle bonus trigger
```

Handling wins:

```
def PayTable(i,wager,symbolCount,symbol):
    LineWin = Payouts[symbol][symbolCount] * wager
    TotalWin += Payouts[symbol][symbolCount] * wager
    Message += "Line " + str(i) +" wins " + str(LineWin) + " credits with " + str(symbolCount) + " " + SymbolMap[symbol] + "!" + "\n"
```

I'm getting the error that both TotalWin and Message are undefined. I thought that I could defined them globally up top?

Comment: I guess you could use the probability distribution to have the 3 same symbols, and based on this, and when this event occurs, choose  randomly among the possible outcome (or with weighted probabilities if one outcome is likelier than others) This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908269/slot-machine-math-probability-of-hitting-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the global keyword in each function to access variables defined in a parent.
For example:

```
def PayTable(i,wager,symbolCount,symbol):    
    global TotalWin
    global Message
```